# Is there a reverse \n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, argparse, difflib

I am making a dictionary application using argparse in Python 3. I'm using difflib to find the closest matches to a given word. Though it's a list, and it has newline characters at the end, like:

```
['hello\n', 'hallo\n', 'hell\n']
```

And when I put a word in, it gives a output of this:

```
hellllok could be spelled as hello
hellos
hillock
```

#### Question:

I'm wondering if there is a reverse or inverse `\n` so I can counteract these `\n`'s.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just remove the `\n`?

Comment: I can't manipulate the difflib list, so I don't have any control over that. If I could I would've already.

Comment: Well, in that case even if there was a "reverse newline", you couldn't use it here. Without context, I can't say for sure, but you can almost definitely just remove the newline off the string. You'll need to make a copy of the list of strings, but you'd have to do that anyway to add a "reverse newline" character.

Comment: If you have the ability to append a "reverse newline" to the end of each string, then you are able to control the content.  If you can't append it, then it won't help you.

Comment: Where do you get the list in the first place? I assume you're using `difflib.get_close_matches`; what do you put as the second argument? Strip *those* strings.

Comment: I use ```difflib.get_close_matches``` yes. And I used ```dictionary``` as the second argument. (```dictionary = open('/usr/share/dict/american-english', 'r')```)

Comment: Just use `.strip()` to remove any whitespace characters from the beginning and ending of a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "reverse newline" in the standard character set but, even if there was, you would have to apply it to each string in turn.

And, if you can do that, you can equally modify the strings to *remove* the newline. In other words, create a *new* list using the current one, with newlines removed. That would be something like:

```
>>> oldlist = ['hello\n', 'hallo\n', 'hell\n']
>>> oldlist
['hello\n', 'hallo\n', 'hell\n']
>>> newlist = [s.replace('\n','') for s in oldlist]
>>> newlist
['hello', 'hallo', 'hell']
```

That will remove *all* newlines from each of the strings. If you want to ensure you only replace a single newline at the *end* of the strings, you can instead use:

```
newlist = [re.sub('\n$','',s) for s in oldlist]
```

Comment: So you're saying that I can put the output of the difflib into a variable, and use ```[i.replace('\n','') for i in x]``` for that variable?

Comment: @JBoyAdvance: yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. I've updated the code snippet to show how to store it in a new variable, one you can use insted of the original.

Comment: Easier than stripping difflib output, strip its _input_: `dictionary = (word.strip() for word in open('/usr/share/dict/american-english'))`.